# While tethering via USB from a mobile phone, how can the cellular signal strength be determined from Linux?

Tags: linux, usb

In my case, I'm using a Pixel 1 device on Verizon. I am running Ubuntu (Xenial). I am able to connect to the Internet, but I'd like to be able to query the cellular signal strength (programmatically). Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try using [HyperTerminal](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490827.aspx) on Windows. There are Linux Alternatives such as [Cutecom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cutecom) or [Minicom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Minicom).

Comment: I found this `AT+CSQ` [command](http://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro.asp) to check the signal strength on Hyperterminal. I think If you get an equivalent tool in linux, you would be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of Android, the only way to do this would be by using USB debugging from your Pixel combined with the ADB tools which I know exist for linux.

This article seems a bit old and is mainly about extract files from the device, but it should be close to what you need because this is what I use on Windows to flash my Nexus 6P (ADB tools). [Android & Ubuntu interaction over ADB](http://tuxdiary.com/2016/02/07/android-ubuntu-communicate-adb/)